# How do i make a warn command for my bot using DISCORDIA(LUA)

Tags: lua, discord

How can i make a warn command in discordia?
i have tried this but the .json returns as null(no error) in cmd, ive been trying for ages i just cant figure out the problem:

```
elseif args[1]:lower():sub(3, #".warn") == ".warn" then
  local wopen = io.open("warns.json", "r")
    local wparse = json.parse(wopen:read("*a"))
    wopen:close()
    if args[2] then
        local mentioned_user = message.mentionedUsers.first
        local mentioned_member = message.guild:getMember(mentioned_user)
        local mentioned = message.guild:getMember(mentioned_member)

        if mentioned ~= nil then
            if args[3] then
                table.remove(args, 1) --// removes command and mention arguments
                local reason = table.concat(args) --// turns remaining contents of the table into one long string value
                if wparse[mentioned.id] then --// checks if the mentioned user exists in the database
                  wparse[mentioned.id] = wparse[mentioned.id] + 1 --// big brain math (if the user already exists, add 1 to their warnings)
                    message:reply(mentioned.username.." has been warned because: "..reason..". They now have "..wparse[mentioned.id].." warnings.")
                else --// if they mentioned user doesn't exist, we should add them to it
                    wparse[mentioned.id] = 1 --// if they don't exist, add them to the database and set their warnings to 1
                    message:reply(mentioned.username.." has been warned because: "..reason..". They now have 1 warning.")
                end
            end
        end 
    else
        message:reply("Provide a member to warn.")
    end

    wopen = io.open("warns.json", "w")
    wopen:write(json.stringify(wparse))
    wopen:close()
```

Comment: please share what you have found out while trying for ages. any debugging attempts? did you break your problem down into atomic steps? which steps work which is the first that doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

guessing your `:sub()` command is wrong.

it begins at position three, but then ends at length of ".warn" which is 5

so `:sub(3, 5)` will never return anything that will never `== ".warn"`

at best, it might give you ".wa"

you need to add three to the second arg in your sub()

```
:sub(3, #".warn" +3) == ".warn"
```

Comment: on second thought +2, whatever it needs to capture that.

Comment: It now gives me no error, but doesn't work either. @Doyousketch2